# Multiple queries with React hooks and Supabase

Tags: reactjs, typescript, supabase

So I'm trying to query a table by `userId`, then query another table from the array I get from the first query.

DB looks like this (a user can have many members):

```
members:
id | userId | channelId | name | ...

channels:
id | ...
```

But the issue is my first query returns an array I need to loop over. How would I implement this in React with hooks?

```js
const useChats = () => {
  const [chats, setChats] = useState()
  const client = useClient()

  const memberFilter = useFilter<DB.Member>((query) =>
    // hard coded for now
    query.eq('userId', '94a9aa95-c794-404a-9a37-7f424b215ebb').limit(10)
  )
  const [{ data: memberData }] = useRealtime<DB.Member>('members', {
    select: {
      columns: 'id, channelId, name, image, read',
      filter: memberFilter,
    },
  })

  const channelFilter = useFilter<DB.Channel>((query) =>
    // issue is here... how do i query `channel:id` for each member entry?
    // memberData is of type `DB.Member[] | null | undefined`
    query.eq('id', memberData[0].channelId).limit(10)
  )
  const [{ data: channelData }] = useRealtime<DB.Channel>('channels', {
    select: {
      columns: 'id, lastActive, lastMessage',
      filter: channelFilter,
    },
  })

  return chats
}

export { useChats }
```

types:

```js
export namespace DB {
  interface Member {
    id: string
    userId: string
    channelId: string
    name: string
    image: string
    read: boolean
  }

  interface Channel {
    id: string
    lastActive: string
    lastMessage?: string
  }
}
```

Using [`react-supabase`](https://react-supabase.vercel.app/) for the queries

Answer (score 0):

You can use the IN operator alongside a mapping function, like this:

```
const channelFilter = useFilter<DB.Channel>((query) =>
  query.in('id', memberData.map(entry => entry.channelId)).limit(10)
)
```